# How to get Multiple images against ID (FK) from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, i-e

```
SELECT `HID`, `HName`, `HDescription`, `ParentID`, `Latitude`, `Longitude`, `CatagoryType`, `Date` FROM `hazara_tbl`
```

and

`SELECT HPhoto_ID, HID, Image, Date FROM hazara_tbl_photos`

i want to get all images against HID. I tried this, it returns me two rows, but i want single row with multiple image.

`SELECT h.HID, h.HName, hp.Image from hazara_tbl h join hazara_tbl_photos hp on hp.HID = h.HID WHERE hp.HID = 49` 
[image: Query result]

i want something like this

[image: Query 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need aggregation.  In MySQL, the typical function to use is `group_concat()`:

```
select h.HID, h.HName, group_concat(hp.Image) as images
from hazara_tbl h join
     hazara_tbl_photos hp
     on hp.HID = h.HID 
where h.HID = 49
group by h.HID, h.HName;
```

EDIT:

The above assumed that `hp.image` is a native SQL type.  If it is a BLOB, then it is better for you to combine the results in the application layer.  MySQL does not readily support arrays of BLOBs.

Comment: let me check @Gordon

Comment: No it returns me only single image, see
 
49      Hotel Jumma Khan       [BLOB - 22 B]

Comment: If you have any identity or auto number column in your table then you can join each row with next and you can restrict the values of HID, HName display at once and it's all the images in the list to next.

Comment: @HamzaJaved . . . My conclusion is that `HID = 49` has only one image.

Comment: @SBohara I don't have an idea how to restrict HID, HName to display only single time + show its multiple image.

Comment: @GordonLinoff but i want its multiple images ?

Comment: @GordonLinoff, i just change the Datatype of Image from mediumBlob to Varchar and my problem solved. Thank you so much